# "string" != "string"

Tags: php, regex, oop, preg-match

I'm doing some kind of own templates system. I want to change

```
<title>{site('title')}</title>
```

Into function "site" execution with parameter "title". Here's

```
private function replaceFunc($subject)
{
    foreach($this->func as $t)
    {
        $args = explode(", ", preg_replace('/\{'.$t.'\(\'([a-zA-Z,]+)\'\)\}/', '$1', $subject));
        $subject = preg_replace('/\{'.$t.'\([a-zA-Z,\']+\)\}/', call_user_func_array($t, $args), $subject);
    }
    return $subject;
}
```

Here's site:

```
function site($what)
{
    global $db;
    $s = $db->askSingle("SELECT * FROM ".DB_PREFIX."config");

    switch($what)
    {
    case 'title':
        return 'Title of page';
        break;
    case 'version':
        return $s->version;
        break;
    case 'themeDir':
        return 'lolmao';
        break;
    default:
        return false;
    } 
}
```

I've tried to compare `$what` (which is for this case "title") with "title". MD5 are different. `strcmp` gives -1, "==", and "===" return false. What is wrong? (`$what` type is string. You can't change `call_user_func_array` into `call_user_func`, because later I'll be using multiple arguments)

Edit:

Strlen $what - strlen title
403 - 5
Heh - looks like I haven't cut the rest ;)

var_dump

string(403) "
title"

Comment: BTW, this is how one writes software with security holes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> MD5 are diffrent. Strcmp gives -1,
>   "==", and "===" return false.

Throw in `var_dump()` and `strlen()`

And this function for especially hard cases:

```
function dump(&$str) {
  $i=0;
  while (isset($str[$i])) echo strtoupper(dechex(ord($str[$i++])));
}
```

Comment: Probably my regex is bad, because it haven't cut off large part of site.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to trim the whitespaces?

```
$what = trim($what)
```

Maybe there is a trailing/beginning whitespace character. Also make sure they are both equally cased:

```
$what = strtolower(trim($what)) //trim and lower
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that there aren't any whitespaces? Use `trim()` to get rid of them. If the md5s are different the strings are different. `var_dump(str_split($what))` will output the string char by char, if a whitespace isn't your problem maybe this helps.

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried to compare $what (which is for this case "title") with "title". MD5 are different.

That would suggest that `$what` is not "title". You should put in some debugging statements in there:

```
function site($what) {
    var_dump($what);
    die();
}
```

Check there's no extra spaces or characters you weren't expecting.